Where can I download Ubuntu for free?
I've tried downloading Ubuntu to my laptop, and to a pendrive, but neither worked, so I deleted them. Now I want to try again, but cannot remember where I downloaded Ubuntu from. I don't understand all the different versions, either. I just want to use internet, email and word processing. Please advise an absolute beginner. Thank you.

You can download all from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ , to learn more about flavors you can view https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours  though versions show the date of release; eg. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is the 2024-April release of Ubuntu (ie. year.month format for main products), which also tells you the supported life (LTS = 5 years for standard support, ESM & legacy support can extend this 5+2 years)...  Ubuntu's specialist products are year in format (eg. Ubuntu Core 24 is the 2024 release)

FYI:  My prior comment starts with where I download Ubuntu from (ie. all ISOs including unreleased ISOs can be located via that link), but an easier link maybe https://ubuntu.com/download

You can download Ubuntu-desktop from here.
Ubuntu 24.04 is the latest / newest version.
